# Files not sent to server: Illegal invocation at File.remoteFunction

Tags: ajax, multipartform-data, fileapi, form-data

I have a function that preprocess a complex object before sending it to server to save some space, so it creates a copy of the object, and got this error on submission (AJAX).

It was working before I decided to create a "clean" copy of the object. 
Why is this error thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that you can´t copy the file object, the spec doesn´t allow it, so, in my function, I had to make every file point to the original file object in order to accomplish the submission of every file:

```
prepareData = function(originalObject){
    var data = clone originalObject;

    data.id_bs = data.bs.id;
    delete data.bs;

    data.id_Cc= data.cc.id;
    delete data.cc;

    //Added this to make it work
    for ( var kDoc = 0; kDoc < originalObject.docs.length; kDoc++ ){
        data.docs[kDoc] = originalObject.docs[kDoc];
    }

    return data;
}
```